# using VB.Net And/Or operators for logical short-circuiting: Any compiler-directive/workaround?

Tags: vb.net, short-circuiting, compiler-directives

I found using AndAlso/OrElse, all the time, VERY annoying. It reduces code readability, especially when conditioning get complicated.

Any suggestions?

Comment: It's helpful to restate the question in the actual *question*, rather than just asking the question in the title, and then going sort of randomly off topic in the question itself.

Comment: That'd be [Yabba Dabba Doo](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Flintstones) , not Yaba Yaba Du. At least get the **facts** right.

Comment: Another sensible path would be to use the non-short-circuiting versions `And` & `Or` most of the time, when it doesn't actually matter whether the logic short-circuits. That adds some self-documentation, because the occasional use of `AndAlso` & `OrElse` will stand out and emphasise that you are relying on the short-circuiting.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm fairly sure there's no (supported) way to change the meaning of `And`/`Or`, and assuming that your code might in the future be maintained or read by other people it would be a very bad idea, you'd confuse them completely.

If conditioning gets too complicated I'd suggest instead splitting it up on multiple lines.
so instead of:

```
If x AndAlso y AndAlso (z Or w) Then
```

Make it something like:

```
xy = x AndAlso y
zw = z Or w
if xy AndAlso zw Then
```